How do I make sure that a component only renders on the client to avoid next edge runtime compatibility issues?
I'm running into compatibility issues using a library with nextjs 14, app router. I'm getting errors that result in this on the client:
https://react.dev/errors/419
and this on the server:
TypeError: Class extends value [object Object] is not a constructor or null

All of my search results for the server error seem to indicate that there is a circular dependency somewhere. I used some tools to find circular deps in my code and fixed them all. But the issue persists. This leaves me to believe that the third-party libraries I'm using either have circular dep issues of their own or are using things not supported in the edge run time.
Is there a way for me to make it so that a component does not pre-render on the server at all?

Answering my own question because it took quite a bit of digging to figure out this workaround and I couldn't find a similar answer on SO. If there are better answers, I'd love to hear them!
I ended up doing this:
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
export const runtime = 'edge';

// using dynamic with ssr false forced the component to never pre-render on server in edge runtime. All errors went away.
const ComponentWithSSRError = dynamic(() => import('@/app/component-with-ssr-error'), {
  ssr: false,
});

export default async function Page() {
   const session = auth();
   return (
      <ComponentWithSSRError />
   );
}


note: This solution is a workaround, using this method means that I'm skipping a lot of nextjs's awesomeness since the dynamic component will not pre-render on the server at all. I much rather would've found a way to make the library work on the server.
